# Is there such a thing as a "Shared OneDrive" (for Business)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, team

Our team currently accesses a shared file server that contains about half a million files. Accessing the files requires either being physically present in the company or dialing in via VPN.

Is there a way to move the contents of the file server to a "Shared OneDrive" so that all team members can access the files **a)** via Web access and **b)** via Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 3):

You've probably hearing a workaround solution on it, where a folder is being shared to people or probably an account where the password shared by different people. But in the product design, there's no such thing as shared OneDrive.

You could consider **SharePoint Online**, that is designed for document collaboration, while a personal OneDrive is targeted at individuals. You would be better off moving those files to a SharePoint document library (or many document libraries if you wish to separate them logically) rather than storing them in OneDrive.

Once the files are in the document library, users can use the "Sync" button in the library to access the library from their desktop (Windows Explorer) using the OneDrive for Business desktop app.

[Sync SharePoint files and folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-and-folders-87a96948-4dd7-43e4-aca1-53f3e18bea9b)

The other solution to this, definitely is **Microsoft Teams**. As the name suggests, it's designed to store files, work conversation, and whatnot, shared to only a small group of people. The backend side of things is still using SharePoint Online. So, administrator does not need to worry about missing legacy files after the account is deactivated (due to resigning or any other reasons).

Comment: Thank you Callum -- I think the SharePoint library suggestion is probably best. Does anything speak against moving the entire existing directory structure from the Windows file server with its 500,000 files to one SharePoint library, and then syncing this to everybody's OneDrive? It would be important that all users eventually see exactly the same directory structure in their OneDrive that they are used to from the Windows file server.

Comment: The only thing that is worth noting is the list view threshold which is 5000 items. This just means that if you want to create your own views based on certain metadata in SharePoint itself, you have to take certain steps e.g. indexing those columns etc. The sync functionality should be fine and it only keeps a local copy of a file on their machine if they choose to or are currently using that file. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Comment: Ok sounds pefect. The Team's files are organized in thousands of folder structures with usually not more than around 100 files in any folder. Could I just try and upload the entire folder structure to a SharePoint library via the browser's upload button, for a test?

Comment: You would be best using migration software to move the content to SharePoint Online e.g. ShareGate, SharePoint Migration Tool

Comment: Thanks very much Callum. I just saw that GoodSync can do it too. I shall give that a try.

Comment: One more question -- when multiple people work on the same SharePoint file via their respective OneDrive in Windows Explorer: there is no way for them to see that someone else already has the file open (other than saving and getting notified that OneDrive has created conflicting file versions), is there?

Comment: PS: and would it be somehow possible to keep the files also on the local network server, in sync with the server copy on SharePoint?

Comment: Multiple people can edit Word, Excel files etc at the same time in SharePoint Online/OneDrive for Business. This is called co-authoring. You would be best off storing the files in SharePoint and users using OneDrive for Business desktop app to access the files instead of using a network drive.

Comment: Really, co-authoring even works when opening the files via Windows Explorer from OneDrive? That would be great. So it would be only PDF files mainly in our case that would create conflicting versions (we use PDF-Exchange Editor which does not support co-authoring). I believe that users are not notified when opening e.g. a PDF file via OneDrive that another user has already open, right?

Comment: Yes, when you open a library file from Windows Explorer (via OneDrive for Business) the usual co-authoring applies. If someone upload/saves the PDF at the same time, there could be a conflict but this is the case with any file system using those PDFs. SharePoint Online has proper versioning though, so that mitigates any problem you would normally see on file shares, in terms of losing data etc.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the Information.